Notation of equations with index: Is it common to always add "for all t"in every equation for a scientific paper
I define an optimization problem for a scientific paper and let's say I'd have the following equations, that all depend on a time index t
$$
x_t > a_t
$$
$$
y_t < b_t 
$$
$$
x_t = x_{t-1} + r_t
$$
Do I always need to add
$$\forall t $$ in every line or is this something that I should just mention once in the text? Of course in this example it is not a big effort to add "for all t" in every line, but in my paper I have more than 30 equations and some of them just exactly fit into one line meaning that adding "for all t" in every line will create ugly line breaks in the equations.

In a presentation, it's not uncommon to dismiss quantifiers, but a scientific paper (especially if it's in a more mathematical journal) requires $\forall t \in ...$. From my limited experience, at least. You can head on over to LaTeX SE, I'm sure you can find ways to deal with this. Making the equations smaller, for example.

@J.Dionisio: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, if I add the for all t in every line, there will be linebreaks and I can't make the equations smaller. The point is that for all 30 equations except for 2, I would have to add for all t which looks a little bit weird in every line. Does it not make more sense to just write somewhere in the text that 28 out of 30 equations are for all t whereas two equations are for all t except for t=0?Further, do I have to use "for all t" only at the inequality equations or also for the equality equations?

If you are using LaTeX, you can make equations smaller (maybe with scalebox or something like that). Maybe what you can try doing when showing you equations is saying "And thus we have that, $\forall t \in \dots$" and you show those 28 equations, and then "And for $t=0$ ... " and you show the other two. But I don't think I've ever seen something like this. Quantifiers should be for both, yes. But as I said, maybe if you are trying to publish in a less mathematical journal they'd be more open to this sort of thing

I think it is OK to say something like "The following hold for all values of the index $t$:" and then list the constraints. You might also get away with numbering the constraints and then adding after the model "Constraints (2) through (95) hold for all $t\in \lbrace \dots \rbrace$".

Thanks for all your answers. I now added the "for all t" in every line. For that I had to use linebreaks. Just from an optical point of view it is a significant downgrade and I don't think it adds any value to be totally honest. Still I will try it that way and see what the reviewers say

I believe you should add the quantifier on every line. The main reason for this is to be precise in the formulation. Even in your small example I expect that the ranges for $t$ actually differ. For example, if $x_t > a_t~\forall t \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}$ then $x_t = x_{t-1} + r_t$ is probably for $t \in \{2,\dots,n\}$ (excluding $t=1$). If I were to implement your model, these details would be important to me.
To format formulations I personally really like optidef. It is available on CTAN and will be installed automatically by most TeX editors when you include the package.

Thanks Kevin for your answer. I added in every line either "for all t" or "for all t unequal 0". Is it okay to add "for all t" or "for all t unequal 0" with the inequality symbol? Or do I need to specify the sets of t with the element symbol?

Personally I don't think this matters too much. One thing you can do is look at papers in the journal you are targeting, and see how they do it.
